# How to get the Azure subscription and resouce group from within a VM using REST API?

Tags: azure, resources, virtual-machine, subscription

A lot of Azure API endpoints require you pass in the subscriptionID and resource group name of the resouce you want to work with.

From a bash script running on an Azure **Linux VM**, how can I get these info? *I can't have the Azure CLI installed* hence looking for some REST API.

There is this old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716805/azure-windows-vm-how-can-i-find-out-what-resource-group-it-is-in) which I found convoluted and requires the CLI anyway. 
One answer even mentions this API to get all info of one given VM:

```
/subscriptions/[subscription-id]/resourceGroups/[resource-group-name]/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/[virtual-machine-name]
```

It seems to be a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue with installing the CLI on a VM.

Comment: what are you tryng to achieve anyway?

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thanks.

Comment: The VMs are created by other team using predefined images which don't contain the az CLI. I'd rather avoid having to download and install it, if possible. My understanding is that the CLI is backed by the REST API so the lack of the client should not be an issue here.

Comment: I'm trying to attach a system-assigned managed identity to the VM where the script is running on. I know which API to use but just like many others it requires the subscription id and resource group that the VM belongs to.

Comment: Well, if you have further problems, please let me know.;-)

Comment: Many thanks @JoyWang.I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it. The [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service) returns a lot of metadata about the Azure VM where the request has made from. I used the following REST endpoint to retrieve the VM's **subscriptionId** and **resourceGroupName**:

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01"
{
  "compute": {
    "location": "",
    "name": "",
    "offer": "",
    "osType": "",
    "placementGroupId": "",
    "platformFaultDomain": "",
    "platformUpdateDomain": "",
    "publisher": "",
    "resourceGroupName": "",
    "sku": "",
    "subscriptionId": "",
    "tags": "",
    "version": "",
    "vmId": "",
    "vmScaleSetName": "",
    "vmSize": "",
    "zone": ""
  },
  "network": {
    "interface": [
      {
        "ipv4": {
          "ipAddress": [
            {
              "privateIpAddress": "",
              "publicIpAddress": ""
            }
          ],
          "subnet": [
            {
              "address": "",
              "prefix": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "ipv6": {
          "ipAddress": []
        },
        "macAddress": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this REST API - [`Subscriptions - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) to list all the subscriptions the user can access for an Azure AD tenant.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2019-06-01
```

For which tenant, it depends on the bearer token you got from, when you get the token, decode in https://jwt.io/, you will find that like below. If you use this token to call this API, it will get all the subscriptions the user can access in the tenant I hid in the screenshot.

[image]

If you want to get the resource group the VM is in, you can use this REST API - [`Virtual Machines - List All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall), no need to pass the `resource-group-name`, it can list all the VMs with the `subscriptionId`, you can get the `subscriptionId` from the [`Subscriptions - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2019-03-01
```

So in conclusion, if you already know the `subscriptionId` which the VM is in, you can list all the VMs in the subscription and find the VM in the result, then you will find the resource group name. If you don't know the `subscriptionId`, you can just list all the subscriptions the user can access in one tenant, and list all the VMs in every subscription. Besides, if you even don't know the `tenant-id`, you can use [`Tenants - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) to gets all the tenants for your account.